# Scraping Data From Udemy , AngularJs Site Using PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, json, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape udemy.com search results But Udemy is Developed in AngularJs framework and i am not familiar with angularjs. I am using CURL method to scrape udemy but the issue is i am not able to get search results because these are generated through angularjs i have searched alot on different different plateforms and got some tricks to get the search content one would say to use phantomjs , But  i also read somewhere in the solution to get the json through php which generates the results, So how would i get the json which genreates the results, or any other way using php to get the results.

Hoping someone can show me right way
Thanks!

Comment: I think what "json through php" means is that the service offers an API which can be interacted with PHP. In your case I would continue on finding out how to do screen-scraping. You also need to consult Udemy's terms of service, it is possible this scraping thing is not allowed.

Comment: Agreed with @ojrask if there is no public API then you will have to handle a different approach (just make sure you read their TOS as there could be some legal implications for doing this), your scraper would have to get the page source and extract information from their view hierachy.  Although this isn't exactly best practice as it's unlikely that they would load more than 10-20 results in at a time

Comment: No this is not the service offers by API. I am just getting page content through CURL an php method but i am not able to get search result. through this