# How to scrape price from Udemy?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

**Note**: I don't find a relevant worked solution in any other similar questions.

[How to find price from udemy website with web scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61904899/how-to-find-price-from-udemy-website-with-web-scraping)

[Scraping Data From Udemy , AngularJs Site Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271192/scraping-data-from-udemy-angularjs-site-using-php)

[How to GET promotional price using Udemy API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61302801/how-to-get-promotional-price-using-udemy-api)

My problem is how to scrape courses prices from Udemy using python & selenium?

This is the link:
https://www.udemy.com/courses/development/?p=1

[image]

My attempt is below.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


url = "https://www.udemy.com/courses/development/?p=1"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)


#data = driver.find_element('//div[@class="price-text--price-part"]')
#data  = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "price-text--price-part"]')
#data=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.udlite-sr-only[attrName="price-text--price-part"]')

print(data)
```

Not of them worked for me. So, is there a way to select elements by classes that contain a specific text?

In this example, the text to find is: "**price-text--price-part**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first xpath doesn't highlight any element in the DOM.

The second xpath doesn't have a closing brackets for contains

```
//div[contains(@class, "price-text--price-part"]
should be
//div[contains(@class, "price-text--price-part")]
```

Try like below, it might work. (When I tried the website detected as a bot and price was not loaded)

```
driver.get("https://www.udemy.com/courses/development/?p=1")

options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'course-list--container')]/div[contains(@class,'popper')]")

for opt in options:
    title = opt.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'title')]").text # Use a dot in the xpath to find element within in an element.
    price = opt.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'price-text--price-part')]/span[2]/span").text
    print(f"{title}: {price}")
```